# Handling new keys in a data binding

Tags: knockout.js

**The setup:**

I have a knockout.js application that displays a table using a template with "foreach: $data.items".

The $data are set with a data-bind like so:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'table-custom', data: {table: 'item-list-custom', config: $root.items, default: {foo: '', bar: ''}}}"></div>
```

The $root.items is an array of dicts, like so:

```
[{foo: 'val2', bar: 'val2'}, ...]
```

I get the values in $root.items from JSON, and the table is created according to the template.

**The problem:**

I wanted to add a new column to the table, so I added a default value for that to the "default" dict (e.g baz: ''). The new column is rendered as a selection (drop down list).

All is OK up to this. My problem is:

1) How do I set the value of the selected option IF it is available? I tried

```
<select data-bind="value: baz, ...
```

but it complaints because the existing rows (from the JSON) do not yet contain the baz key, so it cannot find it.

2) When I choose some value in the selection, for the existing rows, it is not saved with the rest of the model. Ie they still just contain the "foo" and "bar" keys only.

If I add a new row to the table, and THEN select a value, it works OK, and saves the baz value along with the others. I guess this is because the "default" baz value kicks in for the new row, but not for existing rows.

So, how do I get this setup to work with my existing data (that don't have the "baz" property when they are loaded, because I added it later to the table) as it does for new rows?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by prepending your properties with `$data`:

```
<select data-bind="value: $data.baz, ...
```

I created a small JsFiddle that demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/amtiskaw/HD2jt/

Comment: I don't understand, from your description of (2) it sounds like the property is not being populated if it was initially undefined in the rows. In my JsFiddle, the 2nd entry in the list does not define myProp, but this property can be set via the select, and will be saved back to the underlying object, as demonstrated by clicking the "show 'em" button. I do not understand what more is required?

Answer (score 0):

What you should probably do is decouple your view model logic from the template, encapsulate that in a class, and then pass that to the template. This lets you handle various things like defaulting values to whatever it is that you need (as new columns are added or the server-side JSON structure changes) and it also makes the view model more testable. It also enables you to quite easily implement things like client-side editing/adding/deleting of the row data. As for point #2, I believe making it a ko.observable in the view model will solve this.

Here's a snippet of a possible implementation:

```
function TableDefinition(tableName, tableConfig, options) {
    var self = this;
    tableConfig = tableConfig || {};

    // Create an instance of TableRow from each item in tableConfig
    var initialItems = ko.utils.arrayMap(tableConfig || [], 
                                       function(item) { return new TableRow(item); });
    self.config = ko.observableArray(initialItems);
    self.tableName = ko.observable(tableName);

    self.addRow = function() {
        // Allows you to instantly add a new row right from your page without relying on
        // the server-side structure
        self.config.push(new TableRow());
    };
    self.deleteRow = function(row) {
        self.config.remove(row);
    }
}

function TableRow(data) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};
    self.foo = ko.observable(data.foo || ''); // These are observables so that
    self.bar = ko.observable(data.bar || ''); // you can bind the values from
    self.baz = ko.observable(data.baz || ''); // control to view model
    self.selections = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']
}
```

Now you can add this to your root view model and pass the data coming from the server directly into the `TableDefinition` view model.

```
function RootViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;    
    self.table = new TableDefinition('item-list-custom', data);
}
```

And on your page:

```
var dataFromServer = [
    {foo: 'val1', bar: 'val1'},
    {foo: 'val2', bar: 'val2'},
    {foo: 'val3', bar: 'val3'},
    {foo: 'val4', bar: 'val4'}]; // Dummy data, assumed to be retrieved from the server

var viewModel = new RootViewModel(dataFromServer);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here's the associated JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dflor003/BM3HU/

There's a live debug view in the bottom that has the output of the data you would send back to the server in JSON form that gets updated as you change the values.